# How to fake valid json in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, phpunit, faker

In a Laravel project I have to store some data in json. For phpUnit tests I use a factory with faker. I try to fake a json structure for the tests, but it always fail on validation. Is there any proper way to create a json in factory that passes the validation for json?

I tried a simple json array, and the json array with json_encode, both of them failed at validation, and gives errors.

With simple json like: `'settings' => ['areas' => ['full', 'city']]` 
the error is:

```
Property [settings] is not of expected type [json].
Failed asserting that an array contains 'array'.
```

With json_encode like: `'settings' => json_encode(['areas' => ['full', 'city']])`
the error is:

```
Property [settings] is not of expected type [json].
Failed asserting that an array contains 'string'.
```

My model:

```php
class Example extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'settings'
    ];

    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'settings' => 'nullable|json'
    ];

    protected $casts = 
        'settings' => 'array'
    ];

}
```

My factory:

```php
<?php
class ExampleFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Example::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->words(3, 7),
            'settings' => json_encode(['areas' => ['full', 'city']])  // or what?
        ];
    }
}
```

In my test file:

```php
    /** @test */
    public function shouldStore(): void
    {
        $item = $this->model::factory()->make();
        $data = $item->toArray();
        $this->post(action([$this->controller, 'store']), $data)
            ->assertOk();
    }
```

Comment: How are you using the validation? As far as I know the factory would not validate the data. As for the correct approach, since you have a cast that would be to remove the `json_encode`

Comment: In a phpunit test, I send the factory generated data to the controller, and the validation is done by the laravel automatic validation system.
The code from the test added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are casting the property to array, but you are storing a string, you should be passing an array.

Do this:

```php
class ExampleFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Example::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->words(3, 7),
            'settings' => ['areas' => ['full', 'city']],
        ];
    }
}
```

And the rule (no idea where are you using that) should be like this:

```php
'settings' => 'nullable|array'
```

Comment: but what if I want to store datas in json format in databasa (mysql 8 have json field type) and earlier version it will be store as a json in string format... so if the JSON content is not strict, but must be a JSON... array will be good for this case too?

Comment: depends where you are using the validation rules, if it is in a controller, and you are passing a json, laravel will automatically convert json into array, so it must be `array`, if it is a literal string (from json_encode or a file but not a controller), then it must be `json`

Answer (score 1):

Your model works just fine with an array because the cast takes care of the conversion for you. However when posting to the controller you need to manually cast the data to JSON:

```
public function shouldStore(): void
{
    $item = $this->model::factory()->make();
    $data = $item->toArray();
    $data['settings'] = json_encode($data['settings']);
    $this->post(action([$this->controller, 'store']), $data)
        ->assertOk();
}
```

However this does mean that you may need to `json_decode` the data in the controller before creating the model.

Alternatevely you can do what @matiaslauriti is suggesting and post the data as an array to begin with

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the property to `array`:

```php
SomeModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'settings' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I edited my question, because the model already has the casts.